# Make longer strings from substrings keeping new line between each string

Tags: sed, awk, tr

I have a file that contains strings as:

```
GTACGACGGAGTGTTATAAGATGGGAAATCGGATACCAGATGAAATTGTGGATCGGTGCAAAA
GTCGGCAGATATCGTTGAAGTCATAGGTGATTATGTTCAATTAAAGAAGCAAGGCCGAAACTAC
TTTGGACTCTGTCCTTTTCATGGAGAAAGCACACCTTCGTTTTCCGTATCGCCCGACAAACAGAT
TTTTCATTGCTTTGGCTGCGGAGCGGGCGGCAATGTTTTCTCTTTTTTAAGGCAGATGGAAGGCT
ATTCTTTTGCCGAGTCGGTTTCTCACCTTGCTGACAAATACCAAATTGATTTTCCAGATGATATAA
CAGTCCATTCCGGAGCCCGGCCAGAG      

TCTTCTGGAGAACAAAAAATGGCTGAGGCACATGAGCTCCTGAAGAAATTTTACCATCATTTGT
TAATAAATACAAAAGAAGGTCAAGAGGCACTGGATTATCTGCTTTCTAGGGGCTTTACGAAAGA
GCTGATTAATGAATTTCAGATTGGCTATGCTCTTGATTCTTGGGACTTTATCACGAAA

CCGCTGTATTCTCAGCCAAGCGGTATAGTCTCCGCTGTATTCTCAGCCCCAGCCGTTCCACTCAG
AGGAACTTTAAAGGATGTTCCTGTTGAGGGCTCATCATCGTCATCGTCATCATCATCATCATCAT
CATCATCATCATCATCAACATCAACCGTCGCACCAGCAAATAAGGCAAGAACTGGAGAAGACGC
AGAAGGCAGTCAAGATTCTAGTGGTACTGAAGCTTCTGGTAGCCAGGGTTCTGAAGAGGAAGG
TAGTGAAGACGATGGCCAAACTAGTGCTGCTTCCCAACCCACTACTCCAGCTCAAAGTGAAGGC
GCAACTACCGAAACCATAGAAGCTACTCCAAAAGAAGAATGCGGCACTTCATTTGTAATGTGGT
```

that I want to put it as three long strings separated only by an empty line, that is, to be like this:

```
  GTACGACGGAGTGTTATAAGATGGGAAATCGGATACCAGATGAAATTGTGGATCGGTGCAAAAGTCGGCAGATATCGTTGAAGTCATAGGTGATTATGTTCAATTAAAGAAGCAAGGCCGAAACTACTTTGGACTCTGTCCTTTTCATGGAGAAAGCACACCTTCGTTTTCCGTATCGCCCGACAAACAGATTTTTCATTGCTTTGGCTGCGGAGCGGGCGGCAATGTTTTCTCTTTTTTAAGGCAGATGGAAGGCTATTCTTTTGCCGAGTCGGTTTCTCACCTTGCTGACAAATACCAAATTGATTTTCCAGATGATATAACAGTCCATTCCGGAGCCCGGCCAGAG

  TCTTCTGGAGAACAAAAAATGGCTGAGGCACATGAGCTCCTGAAGAAATTTTACCATCATTTGTTAATAAATACAAAAGAAGGTCAAGAGGCACTGGATTATCTGCTTTCTAGGGGCTTTACGAAAGAGCTGATTAATGAATTTCAGATTGGCTATGCTCTTGATTCTTGGGACTTTATCACGAAA

  CCGCTGTATTCTCAGCCAAGCGGTATAGTCTCCGCTGTATTCTCAGCCCCAGCCGTTCCACTCAGAGGAACTTTAAAGGATGTTCCTGTTGAGGGCTCATCATCGTCATCGTCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCAACATCAACCGTCGCACCAGCAAATAAGGCAAGAACTGGAGAAGACGCAGAAGGCAGTCAAGATTCTAGTGGTACTGAAGCTTCTGGTAGCCAGGGTTCTGAAGAGGAAGGTAGTGAAGACGATGGCCAAACTAGTGCTGCTTCCCAACCCACTACTCCAGCTCAAAGTGAAGGCGCAACTACCGAAACCATAGAAGCTACTCCAAAAGAAGAATGCGGCACTTCATTTGTAATGTGGT
```

How to fix this under Unix. I tried with awk and sed but I could not reach the result I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '/./{printf "%s",$0;next} {print "\n";} END{if (/./)print""}' file
GTACGACGGAGTGTTATAAGATGGGAAATCGGATACCAGATGAAATTGTGGATCGGTGCAAAAGTCGGCAGATATCGTTGAAGTCATAGGTGATTATGTTCAATTAAAGAAGCAAGGCCGAAACTACTTTGGACTCTGTCCTTTTCATGGAGAAAGCACACCTTCGTTTTCCGTATCGCCCGACAAACAGATTTTTCATTGCTTTGGCTGCGGAGCGGGCGGCAATGTTTTCTCTTTTTTAAGGCAGATGGAAGGCTATTCTTTTGCCGAGTCGGTTTCTCACCTTGCTGACAAATACCAAATTGATTTTCCAGATGATATAACAGTCCATTCCGGAGCCCGGCCAGAG      

TCTTCTGGAGAACAAAAAATGGCTGAGGCACATGAGCTCCTGAAGAAATTTTACCATCATTTGTTAATAAATACAAAAGAAGGTCAAGAGGCACTGGATTATCTGCTTTCTAGGGGCTTTACGAAAGAGCTGATTAATGAATTTCAGATTGGCTATGCTCTTGATTCTTGGGACTTTATCACGAAA

CCGCTGTATTCTCAGCCAAGCGGTATAGTCTCCGCTGTATTCTCAGCCCCAGCCGTTCCACTCAGAGGAACTTTAAAGGATGTTCCTGTTGAGGGCTCATCATCGTCATCGTCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCAACATCAACCGTCGCACCAGCAAATAAGGCAAGAACTGGAGAAGACGCAGAAGGCAGTCAAGATTCTAGTGGTACTGAAGCTTCTGGTAGCCAGGGTTCTGAAGAGGAAGGTAGTGAAGACGATGGCCAAACTAGTGCTGCTTCCCAACCCACTACTCCAGCTCAAAGTGAAGGCGCAACTACCGAAACCATAGAAGCTACTCCAAAAGAAGAATGCGGCACTTCATTTGTAATGTGGT
```

Note that the expected output has five lines, two of which are empty:

```
$ awk '/./{printf "%s",$0;next} {print "\n";} END{if (/./)print""}' file | wc -l
5
```

#### How it works

- `/./{printf "%s",$0;next}`

  If the current line has at least one character, then print it without a newline.  Then, skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `print "\n";`

  If we got here, we are on an empty line.  Print two newline characters.
- `END{if (/./)print""}`

  After we reach the end of the file, check to see if the last line was empty or not.  If it was not empty, then we print a final newline character.

Comment: Won't a regular expression like `(.)\n(.)` work? A replace string of `'$1$2'` would be enough. Probably something in `sed` can be made, no?

Answer (score 4):

```sh
sed -e:t -e'N;/\n$/!s/\n//;$!tt' <in >out
```

That appends the `N`ext line to pattern space following an inserted `\n`ewline character for each iteration. If a `\n`ewline character is `!`not afterward the `$`last character in pattern space - as it would be if the line just appended was blank - then the inserted newline character is `s///`ubstituted away. For every input line which is `!`not the `$`last I then `t`est for a successful substitution , and if one was necessary branch back to the test `:`label to pull in the `N`ext line again.

And the results are:

```
GTACGACGGAGTGTTATAAGATGGGAAATCGGATACCAGATGAAATTGTGGATCGGTGCAAAAGTCGGCAGATATCGTTGAAGTCATAGGTGATTATGTTCAATTAAAGAAGCAAGGCCGAAACTACTTTGGACTCTGTCCTTTTCATGGAGAAAGCACACCTTCGTTTTCCGTATCGCCCGACAAACAGATTTTTCATTGCTTTGGCTGCGGAGCGGGCGGCAATGTTTTCTCTTTTTTAAGGCAGATGGAAGGCTATTCTTTTGCCGAGTCGGTTTCTCACCTTGCTGACAAATACCAAATTGATTTTCCAGATGATATAACAGTCCATTCCGGAGCCCGGCCAGAG

TCTTCTGGAGAACAAAAAATGGCTGAGGCACATGAGCTCCTGAAGAAATTTTACCATCATTTGTTAATAAATACAAAAGAAGGTCAAGAGGCACTGGATTATCTGCTTTCTAGGGGCTTTACGAAAGAGCTGATTAATGAATTTCAGATTGGCTATGCTCTTGATTCTTGGGACTTTATCACGAAA

CCGCTGTATTCTCAGCCAAGCGGTATAGTCTCCGCTGTATTCTCAGCCCCAGCCGTTCCACTCAGAGGAACTTTAAAGGATGTTCCTGTTGAGGGCTCATCATCGTCATCGTCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCAACATCAACCGTCGCACCAGCAAATAAGGCAAGAACTGGAGAAGACGCAGAAGGCAGTCAAGATTCTAGTGGTACTGAAGCTTCTGGTAGCCAGGGTTCTGAAGAGGAAGGTAGTGAAGACGATGGCCAAACTAGTGCTGCTTCCCAACCCACTACTCCAGCTCAAAGTGAAGGCGCAACTACCGAAACCATAGAAGCTACTCCAAAAGAAGAATGCGGCACTTCATTTGTAATGTGGT
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl's paragraph slurping mode can be used for this.

```
perl -n -00 -e 's/\n//g; print $_,"\n";' gene.txt
```

The `-00` option tells perl to read the input one paragraph at a time rather than one line at a time.  A "paragraph" is defined as a block of text separated by a blank line.

The rest of the script just strips line-feeds from each line of the paragraphs and prints each of them out as one long string with a line-feed on the end.

If you want the output also to be in "paragraphs", add an extra "\n":

```
 perl -n -00 -e 's/\n//g; print $_,"\n\n";' gene.txt
```

Comment: FYI, perl has an enormous number of library modules for manipulating genetic data.  http://www.bioperl.org/ is a good starting point.

Comment: Yes. I started learning perl using this link. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `awk`'s paragraph mode

```
awk -v RS= -vORS='\n\n' '{gsub(/\n/, ""); print}' file
```

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="\n\n";OFS=""}{$1=$1}1' file`

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -p -e 's/\n$//; s/^$/\n\n/;'
```

Reads from stdin or files named, writes to stdout. A practical usage would be:

```
perl -p -e 's/\n$//; s/^$/\n\n/;' file1 file2 file3 >outfile
```

If there's not a blank line after the last paragraph, this will neglect to output a newline at EOF. Handling that is easy enough; just do `echo >>outfile` afterward.

Comment: I applied your command and then I used `wc -l` to count the number of lines. I got 6 instead of 3.

Comment: My code inserts blank lines between the outputs. To use single newlines instead, replace `s/^$/\n\n/` with `s/^$/\n/`.

Comment: works!
Can it be done with `awk`, `sed` ot `tr`? I am not familiar with`perl` (yet)

Comment: Probably can be done with `sed`, but I don't know `sed`. Try mikeserv's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
tr "\n" _ <gene.txt | sed -E "s/__/=/g" | tr -d _ | tr = "\n"
```

A solution with simple commands:

1. Replace `\n` with `_`. Now it is a single line and `sed` can process it.
2. Replace `__` with `=`: these were the 2 consecutive newlines (the empty lines) in the source
3. Remove remaining `_`
4. Replace `=` with `\n`

Comment: if the input is small enough to be swallowed into one `sed` pattern space like that, then why not just handle it there? `sed 's/\([^_]\)_\([^_]\)/\1\2/g;y/_/\n/'`. It is usually a *bad* idea to eat input indiscriminately like that, or, at least, it definitely defeats the purpose of using the *stream* editor.

Comment: @mikeserv I agree. My example is a quick solution for beginners with only the most basic usage of the commands. Other answers have better performance.

Comment: `tr \\n _ | sed 's/__/\n\n/g;s/_//g;$a\'` can simplify the script